# React apollo client: Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I'm using react router and apollo client (v 3.0) in my react project. I have a nested route, let's say `A -> B`, where I use `useQuery` hooks to fetch different sets of data via graphql queries, let's say `QA` and `QB` respectively. In `B` I receive a new message via WS about a new piece of data from `QB`, so I update apollo store cache via `client.writeQuery` for `QB`, however this piece of data also contains a nested entity that requested in `QA`, so this cache update not only triggers rerender of components with `useQuery` hook of `QB` but also `QA`, which produces the following warning:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
>
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

I added the following debug to the `B` component:

```
console.log('WRITE');
client.writeQuery(...)
```

and to the `A` component:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('MOUNT');
  return () => {
    console.log('UNMOUNT');
  };
}, []);
```

and got:

```
WRITE
UNMOUNT
MOUNT
```

So component `A` unmounts after I update cache via `client.writeQuery`.

Why does this happen and how to fix that?

Comment: Could you provide more source code? It's kinda hard to imagine your use case.

Comment: Could you show the way you attach the listener to WS message event?

Answer (score 1):

You can safely ignore this warning, it has been removed in React 18.

https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/82